# Sorting a Set of selfmade objects to an ArrayList (Java)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, set, nested-class

So I have to sort a Set (preferably a TreeSet) of items from the class "Article":

```
public abstract class Article {
    String title;
    String articleNumber;

    public Article(String title, String articleNumber) {
        this.title = title;
        this.articleNumber = articleNumber;
    }

    public String getArticleNumber() {
        return this.articleNumber;
    }
}

public class Book extends Article {
    String author;

    public Book(String author, String title, String articleNumber) {
        super(title, articleNumber);
        this.author = author;
    }
}

public class Song extends Article {
    String interpret;

    public Song(String interpret, String title, String articleNumber) {
        super(title, articleNumber);
        this.interpret = interpret;
    }
}
```

Article is a nested class of OnlineShop which holds the original Set of Articles.
I've implemented the methods to add and remove articels, but I still need an method to sort the Articles of the set: `Set<Article> availableArticles = new TreeSet<Article>();` 
according to the articleNumber value in an ArrayList.
I've tried this but it seems not to work: where unSorted is a List of Articles, but not the String values(how do i extract this?)

```
Collections.sort(unSorted, new Comparator<Article>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Article a, Article b) {
            return a.getArticleNumber().compareTo(b.getArticleNumber());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You talk about a (tree)set availableArticles and about a list unSorted. How do they fit together? What do you want to achieve in the end a sorted set or a sorted list? If you want a sorted set then set the comparator on the tree set and then add the elements you want in that set.

Comment: What does "it seems not to work" mean? Does it not sort properly, does it fail to compile? Also, where is the sort method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your atempt wasn't wrong. I assume that your article number is of the format "1234". Altough it is a String object, wich means, that if you want to sort it comparing its numbers, you have to parse the Strings to an int. Otherwise your comparator interprets your numbers as it's Byte based characters-which creates a mess-.

The untested solution, if my assumption is correct, looks like:

```
   Collections.sort(unSorted, new Comparator<Article>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Article a, Article b) {
                return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(a.getArticleNumber()),Integer.parseInt(b.getArticleNumber()));
            }
```

in my opinion it looks like a mess...better do this:

```
Collections.sort(unSorted, new Comparator<Article>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Article a, Article b) {
        int articleNumberOne = Integer.parseInt(a.getArticleNumber());
        int articleNumberTwo = Integer.parseInt(b.getArticleNumber());

        return Integer.compare(articleNumberOne, articleNumberTwo);
                }
            }
```

thanks to Holger for his advice :D

Comment: There is no member `getValue` in the class `String`.

Comment: sorry i wasnt right in my mind :P i edited it just now

Comment: You can’t invoke a method like `compareTo` on the primitive type `int`. You may use the `static` method: `return Integer.compare(articleNumberOne, articleNumberTwo);`

Comment: That’s why Java 8 is so cool: `Comparator<Article> byNo=Comparator.comparingInt(a -> Integer.parseInt(a.getArticleNumber()));`

Comment: Java 7 developer here :P though you are right. I surly can't compare primitive types with equalsTo(I wasnt sure if it wasnt just with equals).

Comment: thank you ive understood now the concept of the comparator object

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for you input, ive achieved what i wanted with this method:

```
public ArrayList<Article> sortByArticleNumber() {
    if (availableArticles.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No Articles available");
        return new ArrayList<Article>();
    }

    ArrayList<Article> articles= new ArrayList<Article>(availableArticles);

    // sort Methode wird überschrieben für ArrayList<Article> articles
    Collections.sort(articles, new Comparator<Article>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Article a, Article b) {

            int a1 = Integer.parseInt(a.getArticleNumber());
            int b1 = Integer.parseInt(b.getArticleNumber());

            return Integer.compare(a1, b1);

        }
    });
    System.out.println(articles.toString());
    return articles;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {

        OnlineShop myShop = new OnlineShop();
        //Set<Article> availableArticles = new TreeSet<Article>();
        //availableArticles.add(myShop.new Article ("Dell", "1234567"){});
        //availableArticles.add(myShop.new Article ("Alienware", "987654"){});      
        myShop.addArticle(myShop.new Article ("Dell", "9999"){});
        myShop.addArticle(myShop.new Article ("Asio", "9888"){});
        myShop.addArticle(myShop.new Article ("Alienware", "9001"){});
        myShop.addArticle(myShop.new Song ("SSIO", "Bonn17", "5346"));
        myShop.sortByArticleNumber();
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Uncaught exception - " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
[Song [interpret=SSIO, title=Bonn17, articleNumber=5346]
, Article [title=Alienware, articleNumber=9001] 
, Article [title=Asio, articleNumber=9888] 
, Article [title=Dell, articleNumber=9999] 
]
```